# Selecting the value greater than specified in dataframe

Tags: r

I've to select only one value that is greater than the specified value(let's say 14.92) in a dataframe. My dataframe have only one column.

I'm trying something like this

```
value <-data[which(data[,X4]>14.9),]
```

I am expecting a single value that is equal to to greater than specified value i.e 14.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `which.max` which returns first maximum of the group which would be the first `TRUE` when compared to a logical vector.

```
data[which.max(data$colname >14.9),]
```

Or subset `which` and select only one value

```
data[which(data$colname > 14.9)[1], ]
```

Consider an example,

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5)
value <- df[which.max(df$a > 3), ]
value
#[1] 4

df[which(df$a > 3)[1], ]
#[1] 4
```

Comment: which.max returning
0.14142135623731

and other one returns NA

Comment: value <- data[which.max(data$X4 > 14.9), ]
value

Comment: structure(list(X1 = c(0.1, 0.141421356237309, 0.141421356237309, 
0.14142135623731, 0.346410161513775, 0.282842712474619), X2 = c(0.14142135623731, 
0.33166247903554, 0.1, 0.244948974278318, 0.1, 0.141421356237309
), X3 = c(0.14142135623731, 0.223606797749979, 0.100000000000001, 
0.412310562561766, 0.33166247903554, 0.458257569495584), X4 = c(0.14142135623731, 
0.0999999999999996, 0.223606797749979, 0.360555127546399, 0.141421356237309, 
0.2)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @NaumanKhalid 1) Your dataframe have 4 columns, so you probably will need `data$X4[which.max(data$X4 > 14.9)]` 2) I think your data does not have any value greater than 14.9 and that is the reason why you get `0.14142135623731` with `which.max` which is first value in the data and `NA` with `which`. Do you actually need `data$X4[which.max(data$X4 > 0.149)]` ?

Comment: I think dataframe don't have value greater than 14.9
code is working with other dataframe

Answer (score 0):

We can use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(a > 3) %>% 
    slice(1) %>% 
    pull(a)
#[1] 4
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5)
```